# check if checkbox is checked before deleting confirm message using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make sure that the users checked the checkbox before getting the delete confirmation message using javascript. Can someone please tell me how this can be made possible?

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmMER/

**HTML**

```
<form name="deleteFiles" action="" method="post" >
    <input type='checkbox' name='files' id='1' onsubmit="return confirm_update();" value='1' /> file 1<br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function confirm_update() {
    var arrCheckboxes = document.deleteFiles.elements["files"];
    if(checkb.checked != true) { 
        alert("You do not have any selected files to delete.");

    } else {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed deleting the selected   files?");
    }
}
```

Comment: why is your `onsubmit` in the `checkbox` and not in the `form`?

Comment: because I have other checkbox with different name on my original code so I am more interested in knowing how to do it on the checkbox level. if thats possible

Answer (score 1):

The `onsubmit` action should be on the `form` and not on the `checkbox` field.

Secondly, your `checkbox` element was assigned to variable `arrCheckboxes` whereas in the `if` loop you were checking with `checkb`.

The modified code is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="deleteFiles" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm_update();">
    <input type='checkbox' name='files' id='1' value='1' />file 1
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
function confirm_update() {
    var arrCheckboxes = document.deleteFiles.elements["files"];
    if (arrCheckboxes.checked != true) {
        alert("You do not have any selected files to delete.");
        return false;

    } else {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed deleting the selected   files?");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If in case your form has multiple `checkbox` fields and you want to throw error only when none of them is selected (which I think you want). You can do it like below:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="deleteFiles" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm_update();">
    <input type='checkbox' name='files' id='1' value='1' />file 1
    <input type='checkbox' name='files' id='2' value='2' />file 2
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
function confirm_update() {
    var chkCount = 0;
    var arrCheckboxes = document.deleteFiles.elements["files"];
    for (var i=0; i<arrCheckboxes.length; i++) {
        if(arrCheckboxes[i].checked == true) {
            chkCount++;
        }
    }
    if (chkCount === 0) {
        alert("You do not have any selected files to delete.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed deleting the selected   files?");
    }
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/ZmMER/4/)