# How to display confirmation message when a checkbox is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to be able to display a confirmation message when asp.net `checkbox` is clicked, i tried using:

```
OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?')"
```

It doesnt report error, but not working, i later found out that asp.net checkbox doen't have `OnClientClick` attribute.

I have also done a few research on google still couldn't achieve! Please does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use Javascript dialog instead?

Answer (score 9):

After much research i was able to implement this, here is the answer so other users who are facing this same issue can use it:

```
OnClick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to sign out?'))return false;"
```

this works perfectly for me.

Comment: It works, but not why you think!
Turns out ASP.NET prepends this code into its own onclick event. Therefore the element on the page will have something like this:

onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to sign out?'))return false; ;setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$foo$bar\',\'\')', 0)"

So what's happening is that when you return false (or anything for that matter... it could just be "return"... no need for the false, you're preventing the __doPostBack from happening.

So any code here that returns will prevent postback! HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign function to all checkboxes then ask for confirmation inside of it. If they choose yes, checkbox is allowed to be changed if no it remains unchanged.

In my case I am also using ASP .Net checkbox with Autopostback="True" attribute, so on server side I need to compare the value submitted vs what's currently in db in order to know what confirmation value they chose and update db only if it was "yes".

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){                
            var areYouSure = confirm('Are you sure you want make this change?');
            if (areYouSure) {
                $(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
            } else {
                $(this).prop('checked', !this.checked);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at here

[Checkbox check confirmation message.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870997/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-before-deleting-confirm-message-using-javascript)

You can do that  by using javascript, by checking the `count` of the checkbox.

Like below

```
 if (chkCount === 0) {
    alert("You do not have any selected files to delete.");
    return false;
} else {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed deleting the selected   files?");
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: how do i call this in C#?

Comment: did u see the link which I posted, you need to customize accordingly.

Comment: yes i did, but mine is an asp.net checkbox control but not html control!

Comment: you can do the same thing using aspx controls, hardly a matter of how to use the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not mentioned below is jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#yourelemntid_as_enderedHtml').change(function() {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                alert("Are you sure you want to logout."); //checked
            }
            else {
                alert("text here"); //not checked
            }
        });
    });
```

you also better call it on `EndprocessRequest()`  as well as asp loose this script

And in c#

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkgen" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("col3") %>'  
        OnCheckedChanged="chkgen_OnCheckedChanged"/>

protected void chkgen_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      int selRowIndex = ((GridViewRow)(((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Parent)).RowIndex;
      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gridView.Rows[selRowIndex].FindControl("chkgen");

      if (cb.Checked)
      {
             //Perform your logic
      }
}
```

Comment: how do i call this in C#?

Comment: the check box is not inside gridview

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onchange` in asp:checkbox, like this -

`<asp:CheckBox Text="check this out" runat="server" onchange="return confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?');" />`

If you have set `autopostback = true`, it will postback.

Problem with this is it will work for every change - be it check or uncheck, to mitigate this you can use it like this.

`<asp:CheckBox Text="check this out" runat="server" onchange="return Confirmation(this);" />`

```
function Confirmation(element)
{
    if(element.checked) // so that only for checked case, this will execute.
         return confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?');
    else
         return false;
}
```